# Cómo puedo enviar el parámetro correcto al webservice de SRI-Ecuador?

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Al consumir el web service de validación de comprobantes del SRI (Facturacion Electronica), en PHP no logro hacerlo bien, el webservice me devuelve  que no cumple la estructura correcta, ya lo convierto en base64, lo agrego en los parametros.

```
 $objClienteSOAP = new soapclient('https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantes?wsdl');
 $xmlComprobante =file_get_contents("3101201801019041192300110010010000000021234567810.xml");
 $comprobante=base64_encode($xmlComprobante);
 $params = new stdClass();
 $params->xml = $comprobante;
 $resul= new stdClass();
 $result=$RecepcionComprobante->validarComprobante($params);
```

El resultado de la consulta es el siguiente
[image: Respuesta del webservice]
Espero sus comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, no lo envío codificado en base64, lo envío en texto plano y es todo.

De pronto alguien le interesé.

Saludos.

Comment: me sale el mismo error, podrías especificar un poco mas eso de enviar en texto plano, ya que estoy tratando de enviar la peticion mediante xml con la forma esta: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX2vX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX2vX.png)

Comment: Hola, disculpa la demora, lo hice asi, cargo el xml  $xmlComprobante =file_get_contents($directorio."/".$fichero);  luego lo agrego $params = new stdClass(); $params->xml = $xmlComprobante; y finalmente lo envio  $resul= new stdClass(); $result=$RecepcionComprobante->validarComprobante($params); Espero aclara tu duda. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este problema cuando envío a autorizar en ambiente producción, si me autoriza pero no en pruebas el error esta directamente en el soap de envio y autorización

Este es el soap de envio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.recepcion"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:validarComprobante><xml>{0}</xml></ns1:validarComprobante></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

--
Y este es el soap de autorizacion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ec.gob.sri.ws.autorizacion"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:autorizacionComprobante><claveAccesoComprobante>{0}</claveAccesoComprobante></ns1:autorizacionComprobante></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

El error que me dice es el siguiente:
Estado: NO AUTORIZADO
Fecha: 2021-01-13T21:56:02-05:00
Ambiente: PRUEBAS
Indentificador: 39
Mensaje: FIRMA INVALIDA
Tipo: ERROR
```

Espero porfa me ayudes
gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask], ya que esta es la zona de respuestas, donde se espera una. Puedes formular tu propia pregunta y establecer un enlace a esta si pone la tuya en contexto.